# c# - excel - how to store numeric variables as numbers fields

Tags: c#, sql, database, excel, int

I am using oledb and c# to write data into excel.
I'm facing a problem, some of the data which I intend to store in the excel file is numeric(Int variables), but after I try to insert it into the excel it becomes text. Also, just in order to ensure that the data is Int, I am converting it using Convert.ToInt32 method.

When the data is final, which means that I wrote in the code specific number it stays number in the excel, but the other data becomes text.

The results object(in the code) is a Dictionary(String,Object)

```
public void insertIntoDb()
    {
        string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0'", Globals.path);
        OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        String query = "INSERT INTO [SHEET1$] ([Id],[Name],[Email],[Phone],[Complete Date],[Destination],[Passengers],[Depart],[End],[Nights],[Price]) VALUES (@value1,@value2,@value3,@value4,@value5,@value6,@value7,@value8,@value9,@value10,@value11)";
        dbConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", (this.getLastId()+1));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", this.results["Name"]);
        //TODO: Add email to MsgToText
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", this.results["Email"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value4", this.results["Phone"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value5", this.results["Date"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value6", Convert.ToInt32(this.results["Destination"]));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value7", Convert.ToInt32(this.results["Passengers"]));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value8", this.results["Departure Date"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value9", this.results["End Date"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value10", Convert.ToInt32(this.results["Nights"]));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value11", Convert.ToInt32(this.results["Price"]));
        if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Added to DB");
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it I assume that the problem is to write into excel and at the end your int is at text format. It would be easy if you put the code that make the write on excel. Do you use an excel template for your file? If yes you can define the type of the cells in your template to be sure it's numeric. If not you can define the type of your cell before to write in like this example : 
For an integer : xlYourRange.NumberFormat = "0";

You can check the format of your cell like this example :
string checkFormat = range.EntireColumn.NumberFormat.ToString();

Comment: Hi, the code in my question is the code that writes on excel, when I try to define the type of field of a specific row it just skip the row